# ga4 mapping (ga:entrances, ga:bounces, ga:pageLoadTime, ga:pageLoadSample)

Tags: google-analytics-api

I did not find what the following universal analytics parameters are replaced with:

```
universal analytics -> ga4 : 
ga:entrances -> ? 
ga:bounces -> ? 
ga:pageLoadTime -> ? 
ga:pageLoadSample -> ?
```

I tried searching here - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4-dims-mets
but didn't find
Tell me please, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below URL to understand how to measure pageLoadTime in GA4 as there is no direct metric for that in GA4

https://www.lovesdata.com/blog/page-load-google-analytics